# 'setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' in 'android.widget.ImageView' cannot be applied to '(android.widget.ImageView)' Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, mobile

I'm making a card game. But I can't use images. I retrieve base64 string images from FirestoreDatabase and convert to image.

```
private Bitmap convertBase64(String base64) {
    String imageDataBytes = base64.substring(base64.indexOf(",") + 1);
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
}
```

`

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Resimler").document("q7YmpzGVBKhPJnboqwcO");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            base64harry = document.getString("HarryPotter");
            imageViewCard11.setImageBitmap(convertBase64(base64harry));
            imageViewCard21.setImageBitmap(convertBase64(base64harry));
            base64ronweasley = document.getString("RonWeasley");
            imageViewCard12.setImageBitmap(convertBase64(base64ronweasley));
            imageViewCard22.setImageBitmap(convertBase64(base64ronweasley));
        }
    }
});
```

```
private void doStuff(ImageView img, int kart) {
    if (cards[kart] == 101) {
        img.setImageBitmap(imageViewCard11);
    } else if (cards[kart] == 102) {
        img.setImageBitmap(imageViewCard12);
    } else if (cards[kart] == 201) {
        img.setImageBitmap(imageViewCard21);
    } else if (cards[kart] == 202) {
        img.setImageBitmap(imageViewCard22);
    }
```

I tried to convert setImageResources to setImageBitmap. I watched this game's code on youtube. His code like

```
private void doStuff(ImageView img, int kart) {
    if (cards[kart] == 101) {
        img.setImageResources(image101);



private void frontOfCardResources(){
image101= R.drawable. bla bla
```

}

the problem is i have error " 'setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' in 'android.widget.ImageView' cannot be applied to '(android.widget.ImageView)'. I cant use bitmap image.

Comment: But what is the problem? And what is the question? A normal post would contain both.

Comment: @blackapps the problem is i have error " 'setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' in 'android.widget.ImageView' cannot be applied to '(android.widget.ImageView)'.  I cant use bitmap image.

Comment: Put that in your post. Not in a title or comment. Write a normal post.

Comment: Have you considered using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?